# Switching by hotkeys between workspaces with VirtualBox instance

Tags: 10.10, shortcut-keys, virtualbox, workspaces

I faced following usability issue:

when have one of workspaces with focused VirtualBox instance within it,that can't switch between workspaces by <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>.

Is it possible to solve it? (VirtualBox is Win XP guest edition and Kubuntu,host is Ubuntu 10.10)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Virtual Box Manager select *Preferences -> Input* and deselect **Auto Capture Keyboard** to prevent the virtual machine to capture **all** keystrokes of the host when activated:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Press the "host key" (by default: right Control on PC; left Command key on Mac)

The host key gives the control of the keyboard to the host which makes it possible to easy change desktop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> etc.

More can be read on: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html